# CSS3 меню (выделение пункта меню)

Tags: css3, меню

Здравствуйте. Вопрос таков: как под выбранным пунктом меню показать треугольник.
Вот код треугольника:

```
 .arrow {
    position: absolute;
    top: 70px;
    left: 260px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 15px solid transparent;
    border-right: 15px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 15px solid white;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В каком смысле "выбранный"?

Обычно при формировании страницы, текущий пункт меню помечается каким-нибудь классом.

Чтобы показать при клике, опять же, с помощью js добавляете класс.

При наведении, используется псевдокласс **:hover**

Для всех трех случаев (учитывая, что **.arrow** находится внутри **<а>**):

```
li a.selected .arrow,
li a:hover .arrow {
    display: block; /* один из вариантов */
}
```

Если нужно поместить .arrow вне ссылки, то используя css3 это можно сделать так (я не проверял, но должно работать):

```
/* применяется ко всем элементам .arrow,
которые находятся на одном уровне с a и a:hover */
a.selected ~ .arrow,
a:hover ~ .arrow {
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо что ответили. Мне нужен был как раз 2 вариант из вашего ответа.